# How to put Grainy texture on shapes in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, graphic-styles

The grainy texture on Illustrations is trending since last 2-3 years. I tried it, but when I save it as .svg , its size gets increased because of the texture.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to add textures/grain but keep the SVG size as small as an SVG without textures?  If so the answer is no.

Comment: The problem with SVG is that not all tools (or browsers) support all possible features, so this might not work everywhere. You'd need procedural noise to keep the file small. Here's an example: codepen.io/chriswrightdesign/pen/aOpGVe . In Illustrator you can apply Effects/SVG Filters/AI_Turbulence_3 and edit the filter source according to the codepen example. Google for SVG Noise for more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this process in Photoshop, even if my artwork is in Illustrator.
I import them as Smart Object and add noise and combinations of blending modes and so on. That's just what I have found to be easier to control and get a nice result.